# Как изменить рабочий каталог запуска и отладки проекта CMake в Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

Как изменить рабочий каталог запуска и отладки проекта CMake (когда запускаем по Ctrl+F5 и F5) с того, куда производится сборка на любой другой? Для родных проектов Visual Studio вроде все ясно, а вот для CMake непонятно - пробовал добавлять в confugurations файла launch.vs.json поле "workingDirectory", однако ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY` свойство примерно так:

```
set_property(TARGET my_project PROPERTY VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_working_dir")
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY.html#vs-debugger-working-directory

Comment: К сожалению, не срабатывает

Comment: @АндрейСоколов вы указали правильный таргет и путь?

Comment: Да, конечно. Все перепроверил